# Definite integral of absolute value is zero iff . . .

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Given $f$ is bounded on nondegenerate interval $[a,b]$.

I need to prove :
If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b} |f|=0$ if and only if $f=0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$.

The left direction is obvious.
For the right one, following the instruction of the book, here's what I've tried :

If $f$ is continuous at $c$ in $[a,b]$ and $f(c)$ is nonzero, then there's an interval $I=[c-k,c+k]$ in $[a,b]$ such that for every $x$ in $I$, $f(x)$ is never zero. Thus, by including the end points of $I$ in any partition of $[a,b]$, the lower integral $(L) \int_{a}^{b} |f|$ is never zero. Thus, the right direction follows by contradiction.

Using my method, any correction?

Comment: You are using contrapositive, not contradiction.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Well according to a book I read, contrapositive is also contradiction but not vice-verse. :) Kinda agree but then OK if that's ok for you. So, is my method correct?

Comment: You don't mean lower integral; you mean lower sum. And you haven't quite  shown the lower sum is positive, because the $\inf$ of a set of positive values can be $0.$

Comment: @zhw. The book I'm using states that lower integral is the supremum of lower sums. So I'm saying that because $inf |f|$ on $I$ is never zero (positive in this case), then the lower sums over any partition containing end points of $I$ is positive and thus the supremum of those lower sums is positive.
Is that correct?

Comment: You have a good idea, but your language is strange. Why say $\inf |f|$ is *never* $0$? $\inf f$ is what is is. It's not hopping around and changing. Just say it's positive. Now: My main point is the $\inf$ of a set of positive values can be $0,$ right? You have argued  $|f|> 0$ on $I.$ Why does this imply $\inf_I |f| > 0?$

Comment: @zhw. The definition of lower sum over partition $P=\{x_0=a,x_1,..,x_n=b\}$ is the sum of all $m_i(f)(x_i-x_{i-1})$, where $m_i(f)=inf(f)$ over $[x_{i-1},x_i]$. But the definition of lower integral is the supremum of all lower sum on $[a,b]$. I get it that infimum of positive set can be zero. But the lower integral is the supremum. So I didn't imply that infimum is positive. So, how about it?

Comment: You claimed $\inf_I|f| > 0,$ right? How are you getting that?

Comment: @zhw. Oh I get what you mean. Thanks. Then, I'll add the argument. I'm assuming $f$ is positive at $c$,. Then, because $f$ is continuous on $I$, so is $f$ and then $inf|f|=min|f|>0$ on $I$. After that I use my argument in the last comment to conclude. Is it good?

Comment: That's pretty much right.

Comment: @zhw. Btw I mean "so is $|f|$". A bit unsure when I claimed that interval $I$ exists but I guess its ok because what I did was only taking a closed set inside an open set. Ok then.